# Multi-Line/Wave Generator Package for LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphics, backgrounds, technical-drawing

I'm looking at my professors slides now:

http://www.math.ucla.edu/~virtanen/40a.1.14s/schedule/lec1.pdf

The first slides always have these intricate wave lines. If you Google search for "wave lines," you'll get similar results, as, for example, here:

http://www.featurepics.com/online/Vector-Wave-Lines-Abstract-Background-588098.aspx

I'm wondering, is there a package that allows you to create these within the document? If not, how can I get one going diagonally across the page all wild and wave-like from the extreme left to the extreme right of the document.

Comment: That seems to be just an image in the background. And may be it's much more easier to do that (find an appropriate image, and put it there).

Comment: If I were to attempt it, I would first create a fractal path where both x and y were parametric functions of some other variable.  Second, fool around with Fourier or polynomial approximations to smooth the curves.  Third, make minor changes in the parameters to generate several offset+similar curves.

Answer (score 16):

Possibly not exactly what was required but it gives an idea of what could be done:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt,y=1pt, line cap=round,
  show background rectangle,inner frame sep=1cm,
  background rectangle/.style={top color=blue!75, bottom color=white}] 
\foreach \i in {0,5,...,720}
 \draw [white, ultra thin, opacity=\i/720]
   (-\i+\i*3, -0.5*\i*sin \i*1.25) coordinate (A\i) --
   (\i+\i*2.5, -0.75*\i*cos \i)    coordinate (B\i);
\foreach \i [evaluate={\j=int(\i+5);}] in {0,5,...,715}
  \foreach \k in {0,0.05,...,1.05}
    \draw [white, ultra thin, opacity=\i/720] 
      ($(A\i)!\k!(B\i)$) -- ($(A\j)!\k!(B\j)$); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In following example, the principle is the same as the one above, but the coding is a bit more compact/efficient. It takes a bit of trial and error getting the numbers right, but the results can be quite pleasing:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt,y=1pt, line cap=round,
  show background rectangle,inner frame sep=1cm,
  background rectangle/.style={top color=blue!75, bottom color=white},
  declare function={
    xa(\i)=\i/3; ya(\i)=20*sin(\i/2)+20*sin(\i*2);
    xb(\i)=\i/2.5; yb(\i)=10*sin(\i/2)+10*sin(\i*2);
  }] 
\foreach \i [evaluate={\j=max(\i-5,-720); \a=abs(\i); \o=(\a>630) ? (720-\a)/90 : 1;}] 
  in {-720,-715,...,720}
   \draw [white, thin, opacity=\o, rotate=\i/30] (xa \i, ya \i) coordinate (A\i)
   (xb \i, yb \i) coordinate (B\i)
    \foreach \k in {0,0.1,...,1.01}{
      ($(A\i)!\k!(B\i)$) --  ($(A\j)!\k!(B\j)$)
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]